Storage drive does not unmount when user logs out
On Ubuntu 22.04 I have two users that share a storage drive (it's also shared with Windows, therefore I need it to be formatted as NTFS and on a separate drive).
Both Ubuntu users have the auto-mount option enabled on that drive but when one user logs out, the other can't mount the drive because it is still mounted somehow by the logged out user. Only a reboot/shut down fully unmounts the drive.
Is there a way to enable mounting by multiple users of a drive or partition or to avoid leaving the drive is mounted after the user logs off?



that's the structure of the partition (nvme1n1p5) that is shared. My Ubuntu is installed on nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 237,4G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part 
nvme1n1     259:3    0 953,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:4    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:5    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:6    0 194,7G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p4 259:7    0   517M  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p5 259:8    0 758,6G  0 part /media/luggie/Data

/Edit:
After unmounting worked, I had to add this to /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default in order to automatically mount the partition on user login:
#!/bin/sh
UUID="3D0CA1285D46AC42"
mkdir -p "/media/$USER/Data"
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID "/media/$USER/Data" 
exit 0


Try lsof /drive/mount/point/, and yes, without sudo, see if a process is hijacking the drive

I mean: run it from user 1's session, before logging out as user 1 and logging back in as user 2

@kos before logging out, lsof is empty

have you tried unmounting in /etc/bash.bash_logout?

@rtaft No, how can I do this? :)

I just tried this, and I'm getting this too.
I don't know if it's intended or if it's a bug of some sort, however here's a workaround;
I couldn't find a way to do things "the clean way" and run a script upon logout from the GNOME session, I think there's just no facility to do that.
So the next "cleanest" thing I think would be using /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default (which will run as root everytime a session started with GDM is over: the advantage being that this will work for every session started with GDM, including other desktop environments, and for every user, both desirable features in your case).
I'm gonna be pedantic and have you unmount the drive using its ID instead of its path, this is crucial in case of an external drive, whose path is more naturally prone to changes.
First determine the drive's ID:
lsblk -e7 -o NAME,VENDOR,MODEL,ID

% lsblk -e7 -o NAME,VENDOR,MODEL,ID
NAME         VENDOR MODEL   ID
sda           USB   SanDisk USB_SanDisk_3.2Gen1_0401c1c9c83d0b2a25b1128dbbb7c1ae9377813411422a8d5a8c9ce6373d2d71a2fb00000000000000000000887c6f7a00147c1881558107b42f0cf4-0:0
└─sda1                      USB_SanDisk_3.2Gen1_0401c1c9c83d0b2a25b1128dbbb7c1ae9377813411422a8d5a8c9ce6373d2d71a2fb00000000000000000000887c6f7a00147c1881558107b42f0cf4-0:0-part1
nvme0n1             Samsung eui.002538bb31b70164
├─nvme0n1p1                 eui.002538bb31b70164-part1
├─nvme0n1p2                 eui.002538bb31b70164-part2
└─nvme0n1p3                 eui.002538bb31b70164-part3
└─dm_crypt-0
                            name-dm_crypt-0
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
                            name-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

This works only on fairly recent versions of lsblk; if lsblk outputs lsblk: unknown column: ID, you can run:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id

and manually check which symlink points to the device you'd like to unmount (/dev/sda or whatever).
Then edit /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default like so:
#!/bin/sh

id='usb-USB_SanDisk_3.2Gen1_0401c1c9c83d0b2a25b1128dbbb7c1ae9377813411422a8d5a8c9ce6373d2d71a2fb00000000000000000000887c6f7a00147c1881558107b42f0cf4-0:0'

umount $(realpath "/dev/disk/by-id/${id}")*

exit 0

Replacing id with your drive's ID;
Note that umount $(realpath "/dev/disk/by-id/${id}")* will unmount all partitions nested under your disk's actual path (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 etc), which I think is also a desirable feature in your case.

for me lsblk -So VENDOR,MODEL,ID return lsblk: unknown column: ID so I used the ID from sudo sgdisk -i 2 /dev/nvme0n1 | grep unique = EE38DE6F-93BE-401D-B20E-725A69D49F53 and put it into the conif you posted. However the error still persists in my case.
I updated my question btw

it worked for me with:#!/bin/sh UUID="3D0CA1285D46AC42" sudo mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID exit 0
in /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default

@luggiemüller That will unmount only the partition associated with UUID 3D0CA1285D46AC42 (which I guess works for your case since you're happy with the result), using the ID + realpath was a mean to resolve the right path automatically since /dev/whatever may change, then expanding the path to all the partitions (so you don't have to list them all); and yes, actually I can use ID only on 22.04 and on openSUSE Tumbleweed, it doesn't work on older Ubuntu versions, so I added another way to discover the ID by inspecting /dev/disk/by-id

I suggest using $ lsblk -e7 -o VENDOR,MODEL,ID instead, so that only loop devices get skipped. -S excludes my Kingston NVME of some reason.

@Hannu When I answered, before OP edited in their lsblk output, I was under the impression that we were talking about an external device, yes, indeed, -S will list SCSI devices only; I made that lsblk -e7 -o NAME,VENDOR,MODEL,ID (otherwise the output looks weird) and incorporated it into my answer, thanks

Ah... -S for SCSI, ;-)

Okay reminds me on something
Please in
/etc/systemd/logind.conf

Change line
#KillUserProcesses=no

to
KillUserProcesses=yes

so all prozesses are get killed (session-scope) when your user logsout.
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service  

and try again.

This did not solve my initial problem but another one: Before, logging out and logging in between the users, took 2-4 extra seconds where my laptop seemed to go into standby mode, switching off all its indicating LEDs, which it does not do anymore weirdly enough :D

Can you try a complete reboot? Maybe I missed a step (restart another systemd.service) for example.

I did but it did not change as processes that were still acting on the drive while/after logout were not the problem (lsof /drive/mount/point/was empty at that point)

At least it solved another problem. :D
